# How can I format a float in Java with a given number of digits after the decimal point?

Tags: java, formatter

What is the best way in Java to get a string out of a float, that contains only X digits after the dot?

Comment: Have you read the docs? This, like you said, is a simple question that the answer can be found in the docs.

Comment: Sometimes a fast hint can help a lot.

Comment: Usually good research avoids the need to ask the question.  This is not a help-desk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways of dealing with the problem.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final float myfloat = 1F / 3F;

    //Using String.format 5 digist after the .
    final String fmtString = String.format("%.5f",myfloat);
    System.out.println(fmtString);

    //Same using NumberFormat
    final NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
    final String fmtString2 = numFormat.format(myfloat);
    System.out.println(fmtString2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  double pi = Math.PI;
  System.out.format("%f%n", pi);    //  -->  "3.141593"    
  System.out.format("%.3f%n", pi);  //  -->  "3.142"
```

**note:** `%n` is for newline

**Source:** http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 3):

Is [`Float.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29) what you're after?

See also the [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class for an alternative method.

Comment: toString() will let me control the the result only with substr. I will use the foratter. thanks.