# Processing - frameRate decimals

Tags: java, processing

I've been searching for a while now without a solution, probably because I'm using processing.

I've created a "fps" mark in the cornor of my window, but it has a lot of decimals. How do I shorten it down to only show two or three numbers total?

Relevant code:

```
text("FPS: "+frameRate,100,100);
```

Thank you in advance.

*I use 2.2 and not 3, so the nf() thinky isn't a posibility

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a float in Java with a given number of digits after the decimal point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056866/how-can-i-format-a-float-in-java-with-a-given-number-of-digits-after-the-decimal)

Comment: @Cyrbil: This is Processing, which can also be deployed as JavaScript, not just Java. So answers should be in "pure Processing" code if at all possible, that way they're compatible with JavaScript mode as well. Therefore, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [nf()](https://www.processing.org/reference/nf_.html) function that takes 3 parameters, which is available in Processing 2.2:

```
void draw(){
    background(0);
    String fps = nf(frameRate, 2, 2);
    text("FPS: "+fps, 0, 50);
}
```

The `nf()` function that only takes 2 parameters was added in Processing 3, but in Processing 2.2 you can still use the `nf()` function that takes 3 parameters: the number to format, the number of digits to the left of the decimal point, and the number of digits to the right of the decimal point).

You could also just do the formatting yourself:

```
void draw(){
    background(0);
    String fps = str(frameRate).substring(0, 4);
    text("FPS: "+fps, 0, 50);
}
```

Or, if you don't actually care about the decimal points, just convert it to an int:

```
void draw(){
    background(0);
    int fps = (int)frameRate;
    text("FPS: "+fps, 0, 50);
}
```

Comment: OP said it's not an option since they're using processing 2

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Just saw that. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The second option kind of works, except it just stucks my fps on 10.0, where it's set to 30. It also doesn't change at all.

Comment: @Stenberg Please post your code in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My code works fine if I put it in the `draw()` function and print it out using `println()`.

Comment: @KevinWorkman We're using it for a study, and they wanted to make sure we were all using the same version.

Comment: @Stenberg: Understood. They probably should have had everybody update to the latest version then, but I guess it's up to them.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh I forgot to mention, I want to output it into my window, that's why I use "text" instead of println.

Comment: @Stenberg: The code I posted will work fine with either `text()` or `println()`. It just gives you a String, which you can do whatever you want with.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you a lot, I had put my String outside draw, which caused it to fail. Works now, many thanks!

Comment: @Stenberg I've edited my answer. Turns out you can use the `nf()` function in Processing 2.2.